# Period of $Ae^{-i\lambda t}+Be^{i\lambda t}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, exponential-function

I am trying to find the period of $f(t):+Ae^{-i\lambda t}+Be^{i\lambda t}$ on $\mathbb R$. ($\lambda\in \mathbb R, A, B\in \mathbb C$

To find the period, I guess it suffices to find the period of $g(t):=Ae^{-i t}+Be^{ it}$ and we can find the period of $f$ by rescaling on $t$.

let $L\in \mathbb R$ and $Ae^{-i\lambda ( t+L)}+Be^{i\lambda (t+L)}$=$Ae^{-i\lambda t}+Be^{i\lambda t}$ for all $t$.

After computation, I got $B(e^{iL})^2-(A+B)e^{iL}+A=0$ by setting $t=0$.

Therefore, $e^{iL}=\frac{A}{B}$ or $1$ by applying the formula for quadratic equation. And we  can have $L=2n\pi$ or $-iLog(\frac{A}{B})$.

I think $-iLog(\frac{A}{B})$ should be rejected and the period should be $2n\pi$. By assumption, since $g$ is on $\mathbb R$, $L$ should be also a real number, and I guess the imaginary part of $-iLog(\frac{A}{B})$ is most likely non-zero. But I am stuck here.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry it was a typo. It should be $Ae^{-i\lambda t}+Be^{i\lambda t}$

Comment: Should be equal to the period of $\sin(\lambda t)$ which is $\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$. $A$ and $B$ have no effect, with real valued functions they would only change the amplitude.

Comment: Hint: if $f$ has period $T$ then so does $f'$ then so does $i\lambda f \pm f'\,$.

Comment: @SwanKlein this is the intuition. But how to prove $A$, $B$ have no effect?

Comment: @xyz $\displaystyle\;i\lambda f \pm f' \sim e^{\pm i\lambda t}$ must have the same period, which excludes all but $2k\pi / \lambda\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note if $e^{iL}=\frac{A}{B}$ or $1$, then $L=2n\pi$ or $\theta+2n\pi$ where $\theta$ is the argument of $\frac{A}{B}$. We reject the later case, By noting $g(t+L)=Be^{-it}+Ae^{it}\neq Ae^{-it}+Be^{it}$ in general. Otherwise, $B-A=(B-A)e^{it}$ for all $t$ which is clearly a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

1. $A e^{-i \lambda  t}+B e^{i \lambda  t}=(A+B) \cos (\lambda  t)-i (A-B) \sin (\lambda  t)$
2. $\cos (\lambda  t)=\cos (\lambda  t+2n \pi)=\cos [\lambda ( t+2n \pi/\lambda)]$, similar for $\sin$;
3. So the period is $2 \pi/\lambda$.

Comment: It is trivial that 2nπ is a period of g. My question is how to prove $-ilogAB$ is not a period of g

Comment: @xyz, if you want to know if $-i \ln(A/B)$ is the period of the function $f(t)$, make a simply replacement $t\to t-i \ln(A/B)$ and check if $f(t-i \ln(A/B))$ equals to $f(t)$. The result is obvious, $-i \ln(A/B)$ is  NOT the period of the function $f(t)$, if it is not trivial.